# Elastic Beanstalk Health Status is Severe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

*Elastic Beanstalk* health status is *Severe*. Earlier there were no issue on health. It have started to put status as Severe.I can't figure it out, what is causing this issue. My Application is running fine. Logs tell some story but i don't know what to do.

*Platform*

```
Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.2.2
```

*Recent Event* Shows

```
Environment health has transitioned from Warning to Severe.
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for 
all instances. One or more TargetGroups associated with the environment 
are in a reduced health state: - awseb-AWSEB-MWAJRA52EMK5 - Warning
```

On *Enhanced health overview* section it shows

```
Process default has been unhealthy for 14 days (Target.Timeout).
```

*/var/log/nginx/access.log*

```
172.31.31.119 - - [27/Oct/2020:13:53:06 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

*/var/log/nginx/error.log*

```
2020/10/27 12:50:59 [error] 20963#0: *79 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.31.119, server: , request: "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/healthcheck", host: "172.31.27.231"
```

Comment: Is port 3000 correct?

Comment: @Marcin yup it is.

Comment: The 499 error in access log shows that the request is finishing in timeout. You can search if the service are not responding this request or your application is locked in a infinity loop or something like that.